# Why is the last level not reported in R's `summary()`, if its coefficient is not 0?

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding, contrasts

In section 4.7.7 of *Introduction to Statistical Learning* (version 2), the authors code regression contrasts where the last level of a predictor sums to the remaining levels.

My question is, why doesn't the coefficient for this last level (e.g. mnth12) show up in R's summary output? The authors note that it's not reported. But where does this decision (by the R package authors) come from?

The last level of mnth for example has coefficient value 0.37 (negative of -0.37, the sum of the other coefficients of mnth).

```r
 library(ISLR2)
 library(tidyverse)
 attach(Bikeshare)
 contrasts(Bikeshare$hr) = contr.sum (24)
 contrasts(Bikeshare$mnth) = contr.sum (12)
 
 mod.lm2 <- lm(
   bikers ~ mnth + hr + workingday + temp + weathersit ,
   data = Bikeshare
 )

 # Does not show mnth12
 summary(mod.lm2) 

 # Its coefficient should be equal to:
 summary(mod.lm2) |> broom::tidy() |> filter(term |> 
     str_detect("mnth")) |> pull(estimate) |> sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach to include categorical variables in a linear regression model is to use one-hot encoding to replace this variable. That is, to add a binary variable for each level of the categorical variable.

If a categorical variable has $k$ levels, then one must use only $k-1$ binary variables, because the $k^{th}$ binary variable can be determined by the value of the other $k-1$ binary variables. The rationale behind is that using linearly-dependent variables in a regression model with intercept introduces instability into the model.

So, if variables mnth1, mnth2, ..., mnth11 are already introduced into the model, then variable mnth12 should not be used.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This is the reason why the coefficient for variable mnth12 is not shown on the R's summary output.

Comment: I would use a different symbol here, say $k$, so that people new to statistics, or at least this topic,  don't get confused because $n$ is very common notation for number of observations,

Comment: The real rationale is that when there is a linear dependence among the explanatory variables, the coefficients are not identifiable.  (That is not the same as "instability.")  Note, too, that $k$ binary variables are required if no other variables are present in the model (not even an intercept).